# Is it possible to group click events?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project that uses various click events and looks like this

```
namespace Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void btn_obj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMethods.Method_1("text1");
        }

        private void btn_catg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMethods.Method_1("text2");
        }


        private void btn_up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMethods.Method_2("text1");
        }

        private void btn_top_up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMethods.Method_2("text2");
        }

        private void btn_down_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMethods.Method_2("text3");
        }

        private void btn_top_down_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyMethods.Method_2("text4");
        }

        public static class MyMethods
        {
            public static void Method_1(string text) {...}
            public static void Method_2(string text) {...}
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a quite a number of click events so i'm curious if I can group them all in another c# file or a class or something

Comment: You can use partial classes, but you should probably refactor your code.

Comment: You can reuse the same event handler for your buttons but you will need to do some switch .. case..

Comment: @SLaks Can I put all those in a partial class then? And by refactor my code do you mean doing what Israel says?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by *Group* you could also put them in a `#region` and collapse it

Comment: @Plutonix Oh man I didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code-behind, declare a common method you want to call when any of the above buttons fire the `Click` event.

```
private void CommonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Now in your `Properties` window for each button, you can assign this event handler for all buttons:

[image]

Now when any of the buttons are clicked this same event handler is called.

If you want to know *which* button is clicked, you can either use button `Name` or even the `Tag` property.

Let's say we assign a separate unique `Tag` for each button. `Tag` is a property you can see in the property window for each button (and most controls).

Then you can use a `switch-case` statement in your code to identify which button was clicked.

```
private void CommonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (((Button)sender).Tag)
    {
        case "B1":
            break;
        case "B2":
            break;
    }
}
```

Above, `B1`, `B2` etc are the tags I've assigned to each button.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't know how to switch a sender and I used `(((Button)sender).Name)` instead so I don't have to create a tag for each button

Answer (score 2):

usually in the form designer you dblclick on the empty "click" event property to generate new method as btn_..._Click(object sender, EventArgs e).

instead you can select existed method, so multiple buttons can call the same method:[image]

Then in the called Method you can check which control trigger this event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == button2)
        {
            // ....
        }

        if (sender == button1)
        {
            // ....
        }
    }
```